# Almost finishing app and it started crashing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

My app was working perfectly until I installed the accounts-facebook and service-configuration package. Now it's giving this error and I have absolutely no idea how to fix it:

```
/Users/###/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1eul34x++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
                    throw(ex);
                          ^
Error: Can't find npm module 'mongodb'. Did you forget to call 'Npm.depends' in package.js within the 'cfs_gridfs' package?
at Object.Npm.require (/Users/###/proyectos/leads/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:155:17)
at Package (packages/cfs:gridfs/gridfs.server.js:2:1)
at /Users/###/proyectos/leads/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/cfs_gridfs.js:189:4
at /Users/###/proyectos/leads/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/cfs_gridfs.js:196:3
at /Users/###/proyectos/leads/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:222:10
at Array.forEach (native)
at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/###/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1eul34x++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
at /Users/###/proyectos/leads/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:117:5
Exited with code: 8
Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

Comment: sounds like broken package. Remove the packages one after the other again and see when the error stops appearing. Then you'll have found the broken package.

Comment: I already tried uninstalling both using `mrt remove package` but I'm still getting the same error which is rare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What worked for me was simply hitting "Control + C" to stop my app and then running "meteor run" again.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the **cfs_gridfs** package?

Your console reference that package in the error

Comment: I already fixed it, I removed all the packages and readded them. Not sure what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `mrt` it means that you're using an old version of Meteor. Once in a while I had similar issues and I would simply edit the file `.meteor/packages` and the problem was solved when I run meteor command. I'm not sure if the same applies here.